# How do I return the earliest letter in the alphabet from a choice of letters?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am doing an exercise the requires me to return the most frequent letter in a string of letters.  In the event that there are two letters that appear with the same frequency, the 'tiebreaker' is whichever appears first in the alphabet.  For example:

```
'aaaabbbb' #should return a.
```

My code to return the letter is below.  I recognize that it may not be the most efficient.  I'll worry about that later.

```
def mostWantedLetter(text):
    text = text.lower()
    mwl = {}
    for letter in text:
        if letter not in mwl:
            mwl[letter] = 1
        else:
            mwl[letter] += 1

    for letter in sorted(mwl, key = mwl.get, reverse = True):
        if letter.isalpha():
            #letter = sorted(list(letter))
            return letter      #[0]
```

Thank you to the Stack Overflow community for your help in getting me this far!

Comment: Convert to ASCII values or something... Then compare...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def mostWantedLetter(text):
    # count how many times each letter occurs
    mwl = {}
    for ch in text.lower():
        if ch.isalpha():
            mwl[ch] = mwl.get(ch, 0) + 1

    # ordered descending by count (highest first) then ascending by letter
    least = min(mwl.items(), key=lambda x:(-x[1], x[0]))

    # return the letter from the least item
    return least[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations on making it thus far. I'll offer two hints:

Hint 1: modify the `key` argument to `sorted()` to take into account both the letter's count and its position in the alphabet.

Hint 2: look into how Python compares tuples.

On a separate note, [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) are worth knowing about.

Answer (score 3):

Right, I found this and it was pretty damn cool:

```
>>> import collections
>>>
>>> ordered1 = collections.Counter('aaaabbbb').most_common(1))
>>> ordered1[0][0]
'a'
>>>
>>> ordered2 = collections.Counter('abb').most_common(1))
>>> ordered2[0][0]
'b'
```

This puts letters in order primarily of occurrence, and then if two letters occur equal times then they are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Feedback is welcome! I am always looking to improve my posts.

Comment: Won't work with a string like `abb`. You missed the "most frequent letter" point.

Comment: also, there's no reason to create a new string after you've sorted the individual characters (i.e. no reason to use `''.join`), just do `sorted(my_string)[0]`

Comment: @Matthias See edits. I think I came up with something really cool. Consider undoing downvote and possibly upvote if you consider it valid and useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
def most_wanted(s):
    return chr(min(set([ord(x) for x in list(s)])))
```

It breaks the string into a list and then converts them all to their ascii representation. It makes this a set so that duplicates don't need to be compared. It takes the minimum value from these and then converts it back to a letter.